# How to display a polynomial function using printf in Scilab? {Without using disp}

Tags: scilab

Here is my code. It throws error. I want to printf the polymial.

```
clc
clear
printf("Example 4.4 | Page number 103 \n\n");
//find Cv and Cp
//Given data
t = poly(0,'t'); //°C //Temperature in °C
u = 196 + .718*t; //KJ/kg //specific internal energy
pv = 287*(t+273); //Nm/kg //p is pressure and v = specific volume

//Solution
Cv = derivat(u);
printf("Cv = %.3f KJ/kgK\n",Cv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of derivat is another polynomial. You can check with:

```
disp(typeof(Cv))
```

The scilab types are listed [here](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/type.html).

You can get the sole coefficient out by using [coeff](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/coeff.html)

```
printf("Cv = %.3f KJ/kgK\n",coeff(Cv));
```